# Loading undefined number of file contents with ajax by config only one sucess listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript, ecmascript-6

i have a json config that has a array of objects, containing file names. and i need to load them in a row and have a event when all files are ready loaded for displaying them as code snippet on my homepage.

config.json:

```
{
  "author": "TypedSource",
  "date": "2017-04-16",
  "files": [
    {
      "lang": "HTML",
      "fileName": "sample.html.txt"
    },
    {
      "lang": "PHP",
      "fileName": "sample.php.txt"
    },
  ] 
}
```

TypeScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('config.json')
    .ready(function(data){
      console.log('success on loading config');
      $.when(
        // i want to load every file here
        // but this for can't work inside the $.when
        // it is just pseudo code for explain what i want to do
        for(let i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
          $.get(data.files[i].fileName);
        }
      }.then(
        function(){
          // success listener for all files loaded
          console.log('success on loading all files');
          console.log(arguments);
          // now build the template for each response[0] and bind it to highlight.js code block
        }
        function(){
          // error listener if a file can't be loaded
          // ATTENTION: if an error occured, no single success is given
          console.error('error on loading files');
          console.log(arguments[0].responseText());
        }
      )
    })
    .fail(function(){
      console.error('error on loading config file');
      console.log(arguments[0].responseText);
    });
});
```

$.get only accepts 1 url to load, $.when is the option i know, but normaly i have to assign every call inside the when by hand. does somebody know how to handle it?

Comment: if it is possible i don't want to build a single request for every file and write a wrapping listener that checks if the count of successed ajax calls is the same like the number of entries in files array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of the request promises to pass to [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which won't resolve until all request promises have resolved

```
$.getJSON('config.json').then(function(config) {
  var requests = config.files.map(function(file) {
    return $.get(file.fileName);
  });

  Promise.all(requests).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
    res.forEach(function(txt) {
      $('body').append('<p>' + txt + '</p>')
    });
  });
});
```

The order of the results array in Promise.all() will be the same as the files array order in your config file

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FO6z4DtBErOzKDM80cTF?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: looks like this is what i want, but i get a transpiler error: `Error:(83, 25) TS2693:'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: Promise is a window property in browser...not sure what transpiler you are using ... could try `window.Promise.all()`

Comment: Error:(84, 32) TS2339:Property 'Promise' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: `window` is lower case. Should be easy search how to use `window` in typescript. I personally don't use typescript much

Comment: i found the sollution, it was a ts config porblem. `"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "../public_html/js/ts.js",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ]
  },` adding the lib entries  to tsconfig.json resolved it.